# Kendo Datepicker z index

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a dynamically generated list of inputs inside a kendo accordion panel.

The inputs are generated like this:

```
rowContent += "<td><input " + checked + " class='" + field.FieldTypeInput + "' type='" + field.FieldTypeInput + "' id='FldList_" + rowLength + "__UpdatedValue'  value='" + currentValue + "' name='FldList[" + rowLength + "].UpdatedValue' ></td>";
```

Some of these inputs are dates which are turned into Kendo date pickers :

```
$('.datepicker').kendoDatePicker({

});
```

The problem I am facing is the date popup is appearing beneath the panel (Or anything outside of the li it is in.

I have tried this:

```
$('.datepicker').kendoDatePicker({
     //comment the beforeShow handler if you want to see the ugly overlay
    open: function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
             $('.ui-datepicker').css('z-index', 8888);
        }, 1);
    }
});
```

If I break the scipt by calling 
    $('.datepicker').bob it break the script and therefore works (But obviously breaks the rest of the javascript functionality too.

I have also tried this:

```
$("input[type=date]").kendoDatePicker({
    open:function(e)
        {                
            window.setTimeout(function(){ $(".k-calendar-container").parent(".k-animation-container").css("zIndex", "11000"); }, 1);
        }
  });
```

I have also tried changing the style:

```
position: relative; z-index: 100000;
```

And now I am completely out of ideas.

Is anyone able to help me?

Many thanks

Edit:

I have noticed that the jQuery function I am using doesn't appear to be setting the Z-Index at all. I tried to change $('.ui-datepicker').css('z-index', 8888); to $('.k-calendar-container').css('z-index', 8888); but that didn't work either. I will keep updating as I find more info

Comment: Can you do the reverse and try lowering the z-index on the panel?

Comment: According to Firebug the panel only has a z-Index of 5. So that shouldn't get in the way. 

I am wondering if it is an overflow problem but changing the overflow doesnt help (At best it creates a scrollbar on that panel)

Comment: OK.  So you also set the z-index on the datepicker calendar dropdown in FireBug, and did that help at all?  The complexity with kendo is there are various hierarchy of nested elements...

Comment: No that didn't help. The only way I have got close is to brek jQuery in the Open function which then prevents it from giving it a Z-Index of 6.

Answer (score 0):

Try turn off datePicker animation and see if it helps:

```
$('.datepicker').kendoDatePicker({
     //comment the beforeShow handler if you want to see the ugly overlay
    open: function () {
        $('.ui-datepicker').css('z-index', 8888);
    },
    animation: {
        open: {
            duration: 0
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that didn't work. I have just noticed that the function isn't actually setting the z-Index of the container.